# Is matrix $A$ totally unimodular?

Tags: matrices, total-unimodularity

[image]

Currently, I am looking at matrix $A$ and I am wondering if it is totally unimodular (TU).

I would like to clarify if I truncate matrix $A$ such that the right hand side of the matrix is an identity matrix, then can I say that it is TU? Otherwise, how should we be explaining TU for this matrix?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: TU = Totally Unimodular (think that all acronisms should be given their in extenso names)

Answer (score 3):

This matrix is clearly not totally unimodular. The top-left entry is $2$. For TU matrices only entries from $\{-1,0,1\}$ are allowed.